# ChartJS - how to sort and display legend

Tags: charts, react-chartjs

I need your help. I have chartjs (react) - Areachart and legend.

is it possible to sort legend or change position of legend values?

We have now 16-18 (blue, on bottom) then 04-06 (orange ) ....

I would like to have:
01-03-Green on bottom, then 04-06 orange, 07-09 purple.

how to do that?

tnx a lot

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure that if you re-order your datasets before adding them to ChartJS you'll get the results you're looking for.